# Image in the appBarLayout

Tags: android, android-toolbar

What I want to achieve is almost the same result as is on picture, but without collapsing and with tab layout under toolbar text. I got it done using `CollapsingTollbarLayout`, but I don't think that's a good way if I don't want it to colapse. 
How should I properly implement the image, so it's under the toolbar and tab layout ?

[image: Example]

Comment: don't use CollapsingTollbarLayout  use simple Toolbar

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/32607496/android-toolbar-how-to-have-a-toolbar-with-imalge-in-the-background-and-menu-ite   link for reference

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, here is the solution :

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewplaces"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/pyrros" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/caj_tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imageViewplaces"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MineCustomTabText"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do like this

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.mobiona.kriddr.view.activity.ProviderDetailsActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@android:color/white"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextViewStyle.White"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextViewStyle"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:id="@+id/imageName"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:theme="@style/Toolbar"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/yourotherpartofxml" />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 4):

Hope this helps. [check this render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpHaC.jpg)

```
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="256dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:titleEnabled="false"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/home_appbar_screen"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/headPink"
                    app:tabMode="fixed"
                    />


            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/backPurple"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="fitStart"
                    android:src="@drawable/home_background_screen" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/test"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```